# Using .equals() in while loop causing program to hang on execution

Tags: performance, while-loop, string-comparison

I had the below while loop:

```
Vault vlt = mapper.readValue(currentLine, Vault.class);
while(vlt.getvault_name() == vault)){
                        byteCount += vlt.getBytes();
}
```

vlt.getvault_name returns the vault name as a String and vault is also a String. My program runs with this but whilst the condition does be true the byteCount never incrememts. I then realised that I should actually use .equals() when comparing String values so changed my loop as follows.

```
Vault vlt = mapper.readValue(currentLine, Vault.class);
while(vlt.getvault_name().equals(vault)){
                        byteCount += vlt.getBytes();
}
```

Now I'm trying to tun my program but it seems to be hanging. It's been sitting as if trying to execute for 45 minutes now when it usually takes about 30 seconds. There are no errors though.

As this is the only thing that's changed my question is are there any performance implications around using .equals()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is happening because the while loop has transformed into an infinite loop. During each iteration the while loop is checking the value of the same object with a string. It looks like you need a if condition compared to a while loop for this case.